# いつしか+noun , what does it mean?

Tags: adverbs

In a Dragon Ball's novel, a paragraph says:

> しかし、**いつしか**サイア人は、圧倒的な力を持つコルド大王に支配されていた。

This could be? :

> However, an unknown sayajin  was taking control of Cold Great Kind who had an overwhelming power.

Thanks.

Comment: The full sentence, or better yet the full paragraph, would be far more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いつしか does not mean "unnoticed." It's essentially equivalent to いつか ("sometime"), but with greater emphasis on the idea of uncertainty. In some cases, it means something like "at some point" or "at some time or other" (in either the past or the future), while in others it conveys the sense of time passing without one's being fully aware of it. As Aeon Akechi has noted in a comment, it isn't really possible to translate the phrase you've quoted without more context, but perhaps the 例文 on this page will help you get a sense of the range of possible meanings: [https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/いつしか](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B)

Edited to add: Now that you've edited your original post to include the whole sentence, it's a little clearer – though as 圧倒的を makes no sense, I'm guessing there's a typo in either your post or your book. (It should be 圧倒的な).

I'm not at all familiar with Dragonball and had to use Google to find the conventional English translations for コルド大王 and サイア人, but it looks as if the sentence you have quoted would be something like "However, at some point in time the Saiyans came to be ruled by King Cold, who had overwhelming power." Presumably the preceding paragraph(s) have some information about what life was like for the Saiyans in the halcyon days before this unfortunate state of affairs came to pass.

As a final note, while I'm new to this site myself, I think in general it's helpful if you avoid editing your posts without indicating that you have done so, and how you have edited them – particularly if others have already responded!